# Android button outside of a text view

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

What is the best way to achieve the following UI where I want a button to appear "outside" and above a TextView?

Here's what I want to do (expected), the code I've written for it, and how it appears in my emulator (actual).

Expected: the "x" button is outside of the text view

[image]

My Layout:
(also, note: I'm inflating the `bottom_sheet_layout` in a class that extends `com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment`)

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/blue">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_menu_delete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_x"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_cancel_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_sheet_menu_delete"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Actual:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

change the `layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf` id of Button
move background from parent to TextView

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_menu_delete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@color/blue"//add background
        android:text="Delete"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_x"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_cancel_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_sheet_menu_delete"//change id
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/blue">

    

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_x"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_cancel_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_sheet_menu_delete"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_menu_delete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this -->

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_x"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:background="@drawable/your_cross_image"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bottom_sheet_x"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,NotSibling">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_menu_delete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```